# adding objects with foreign keys without having to provide the foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have an asp.net-mvc project with the following set up:

```
class Person {
 int PersonId {get; set;}
 List<Activity> Activities {get; set;}
} 
class Activity {
 int ActivityId {get; set;}
 int PersonId {get; set;}
 [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
 Person Person {get; set;}
}
```

now, when I add a new activity for a person, I send an ajax POST and the action method does the following:

```
public ActionResult AddActivity(int Id) {
 var activity = new Activity();
 activity.PersonId = Id;
 db.Activity.Add(activity);
 db.SaveChanges();  
}
```

is this a bad way of adding an activity because I'm manually adding the foregin key?

is there a way to do this without having to provide the `PersonId` foreign key and let it be generated automatically (maybe getting the person object, updating its list of activities and then marking it as `EntityState.Modified`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly legitimate.

When you create a new instance of an entity, there is no way EF knows in advance what value a foreign key needs to be, it only cares that it's valid if you specify one before you save the object back to the database.

Imagine you have multiple foreign keys ... how else would you assign them?!

You can try adding an EF object to a parent collection property, but doing so won't update the associated foreign key. That would kind of make sense, but then again, there's the problem with multiple foreign keys.